# Print preview only prints current page

Tags: vb.net, printing, vb.net-2010

Really not sure what I'm doing in VB.net when it comes to printing, but I have a printing sub that displays a print preview.

The print preview has 4 pages, but when I click on the print button, it only prints the last page.

On the form I have `PrintDialog1` `PrintDocument1` and `PrintPreview1`.

My button has the command

```
 me.printpreviewdialog1.showdialog()
```

My `PrintDocument1_PrintPage` contains the code for printing.

I am also using the `e.HasMorePages=True` and `False` via a counter to control pages

Any Ideas?

Comment: can you show some more of the code please specifically the logic to determine the `HasMorePage` property value

Comment: I've managed to fix it. The answer was to reset my page count variable after the e.HasMorePages=False. Not sure why that should make it work as it's my own defined variable and not a system one.